# nslookup not working but ping and traceroute with ICMP does work fine

Tags: networking, dns

In the network I am having troubles with, nslookup against dns server 1.1.1.1 with google.at. does not work, but a ping to 1.1.1.1 is successfull. Also a traceroute does work, but only with ICMP packages.
Also using 8.8.8.8 as dns server does not work either.

This problems occurs on a MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2014 running macOS High Sierra.
Also, it seems like the problem only occurs on my device, the other devices in the network are working fine.

output of nslookup

```
$ nslookup
> set d2
> server 1.1.1.1
flush_server_list()
make_server(1.1.1.1)
Default server: 1.1.1.1
Address: 1.1.1.1#53
> google.at.
addlookup()
make_empty_lookup()
looking up google.at.
start_lookup()
setup_lookup(0x7f80a8010208)
resetting lookup counter.
cloning server list
clone_server_list()
make_server(1.1.1.1)
using root origin
recursive query
add_question()
starting to render the message
done rendering
create query 0x10858d008 linked to lookup 0x7f80a8010208
do_lookup()
send_udp(0x10858d008)
bringup_timer()
have local timeout of 5
working on lookup 0x7f80a8010208, query 0x10858d008
sockcount=1
recving with lookup=0x7f80a8010208, query=0x10858d008, sock=0x10858f000
recvcount=1
sending a request
lock_lookup /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/bind9/bind9-57.3/bind9/bin/dig/dighost.c:2743
success
send_done()
sendcount=0
check_if_done()
list empty
unlock_lookup /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/bind9/bind9-57.3/bind9/bin/dig/dighost.c:2774
```

output of ping

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=12.682 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=10.296 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=10.796 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=12.408 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=10.391 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 10.296/11.315/12.682/1.022 ms
```

output of traceroute with UDP packages

```
$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.696 ms  0.386 ms  0.252 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
^C
```

output of traceroute with ICMP packages

```
$ traceroute -I 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.732 ms  0.352 ms  0.272 ms
 2  * * *
 3  212.33.34.109 (212.33.34.109)  7.246 ms  6.210 ms  5.987 ms
 4  212.33.35.174 (212.33.35.174)  7.908 ms  9.502 ms  7.318 ms
 5  193.203.0.195 (193.203.0.195)  10.286 ms  12.702 ms  10.484 ms
 6  1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1)  13.425 ms  11.694 ms  10.511 ms
```

EDIT:
output of tcpdump during website call in safari (nslookup did not lead to any output of the command)

```
$ sudo tcpdump -iany port 53
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
19:36:00.117430 IP 192.168.0.11.64652 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 43155+ A? google.at. (27)
19:36:00.125909 IP 192.168.0.11.61744 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38849+ PTR? 1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa. (38)
19:36:01.130751 IP 192.168.0.11.61744 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38849+ PTR? 1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa. (38)
19:36:03.131708 IP 192.168.0.11.61744 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38849+ PTR? 1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa. (38)
19:36:05.117436 IP 192.168.0.11.64652 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 43155+ A? google.at. (27)
19:36:07.134725 IP 192.168.0.11.61744 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38849+ PTR? 1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa. (38)
19:36:07.890420 IP 192.168.0.11.51727 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 24358+ A? gateway.fe.apple-dns.net. (42)
19:36:08.087105 IP 192.168.0.11.63601 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 5775+ A? outlook.fh-ooe.at. (35)
19:36:08.895728 IP 192.168.0.11.51727 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 24358+ A? gateway.fe.apple-dns.net. (42)
19:36:10.118645 IP 192.168.0.11.64652 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 43155+ A? google.at. (27)
19:36:10.896498 IP 192.168.0.11.51727 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 24358+ A? gateway.fe.apple-dns.net. (42)
19:36:14.901699 IP 192.168.0.11.51727 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 24358+ A? gateway.fe.apple-dns.net. (42)
19:36:15.139180 IP 192.168.0.11.61744 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38849+ PTR? 1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa. (38)
19:36:30.336824 IP 192.168.0.11.63537 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38627+ A? api-glb-fra.smoot.apple.com. (45)
19:36:31.656916 IP 192.168.0.11.56392 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 369+ A? mail.google.com. (33)
19:36:34.145445 IP 192.168.0.11.64274 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 15319+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
19:36:35.148576 IP 192.168.0.11.64274 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 15319+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
19:36:37.153460 IP 192.168.0.11.64274 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 15319+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
19:36:38.337756 IP 192.168.0.11.63537 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 38627+ A? api-glb-fra.smoot.apple.com. (45)
19:36:41.158234 IP 192.168.0.11.64274 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 15319+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
19:36:46.351481 IP 192.168.0.11.59502 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 45992+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
19:36:49.161336 IP 192.168.0.11.64274 > 1.1.1.1.domain: 15319+ A? accounts.google.com. (37)
^C
22 packets captured
9589 packets received by filter
1729 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Run `tcpdump -iany port 53` while you use `nslookup`. There seems to be some kind of filter or firewall.

Comment: @RalfFriedl sorry but nslookup did not lead to any output in the tcpdump so i tried to access a site via safari, hope this also helps since it's also about domain name resolving.

Comment: It looks like you might have a home router with address 192.168.0.1? Have you tried resetting it?

Comment: @StanleyYu do you mean a complete factory reset? I tried to play with the DHCP settings, but this did not help either. It's just strange that just my machine is affected, so how do you suggest is the router affecting just one machine?

Comment: @ManuelFuchs I meant a simple power cycle. While you're at it, might as well reset everything you have control over (Mac, modem, switch, etc.) You might have already tried this already, but I wanted to be sure. It looks like something is blocking your UDP packets: tcpdump output shows outbound DNS requests, but nothing coming back; UDP traceroute also fails. If resetting doesn't work, you may have to take a look at your Mac's firewall and/or the router firewall for some sort of rule. If that fails, try a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that `nslookup` wouldn't generate any DNS queries.

As seen in the output of `tcpdump`, you don't get any answer form the server at `1.1.1.1`.

There are some possible reasons for this:

- There ins't a DNS server running on that server.
- There is a DNS server, but it's configured to not answer to queries from your address.
- Something is blocking your DNS requests and they don't even reach the DNS server.
- Something is blocking the DNS answers from the server on the way back.

As you say that other devices in the same network are get answers from that server, it is likely that you have a local firewall that blocks the DNS packets. You could run `tcpdump` on another device on your network and see whether it receives DNS packets that you generate.

Comment: Options 1, 2 and 4 can't really be because 1.1.1.1 is a official cloud flare server and if the requests back from the server would get filtered, then none of the devices in the network would be able to use it or am I wrong @RalfFriedl ?
So I am left with option 3, I am gonna investigate more, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your DNS server --> services --> DNS has the check on ON next to where it says DNS Service