# Can ping 8.8.8.8 but cannot resolve DNS

Tags: networking, mac, connection

I can't browse the internet on a MacBook Pro, no matter if connected via WiFi or Ethernet. My ISP works fine as I can use other devices.
I noticed I can ping 8.8.8.8 while nslookup using 8.8.8.8 as server returns nothing.

I already tried restarting the laptop and firewall is disabled.

*Trying to understand the root cause, I noticed the laptop can ping 1.0.0.1 while 1.1.1.1 goes timeout. This is extremely weird and I think by solving this, the overall problem would be fixed.How can it be?*

**EDIT:**
actually I noticed the ISP can reach 1.0.0.1 while it cannot reach 1.1.1.1 so this is no longer considered related to the issue of the Mac.

**EDIT2**: editing the question I noticed it's very much similar to [nslookup not working but ping and traceroute with ICMP does work fine](https://superuser.com/q/1361300/616946)

Comment: Have you been using a VPN of some kind?

Comment: You could traceroute the DNS, but I think it's related to Clouflare anyway. Apparently, in some parts of the world, Clouflare routes traffic through country-based servers to comply with local laws. Seems to be the case in Russia with 1.0.0.1. See here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/why-the-dns-1-0-0-1-is-faster-than-1-1-1-1-for-me/24026/12. I'm in France, and we have access to the new DNS in 1.1.1.2 and 1.0.0.2 that are supposed to keep malware away. Those are the ones I use on my PC.

Comment: I didn't know that 1.0.0.1 sometimes sees different routing from 1.1.1.1.  However, Cloudflare uses anycast, so having a locally routed copy of either of those servers is quite normal even in countries with no such requirements.

Comment: Still, a traceroute would be useful as it might reveal your local sysadmin having decided to use 1.1.1.1 for their own purposes (as many had).

Comment: @JakeGould no VPN used

Comment: @Didier yes I noticed the fact 1.1.1.1 cannot be reached depends on the ISP so I changed the question

Comment: ping and nslookup work on different layers. ping uses ICMP and works on the IP layer only, while nslookup requires UDP/TCP and works on the transport layer. You can try a tool like netcat, which does simple UDP/TCP testing just to ensure that you can reach the far-end and create a socket (separates issues with listening service). If you can't even create a socket with netstat, then something is blocking at the transport layer between you and the far-end.